# NoSuchMethodError The method '[]' was called on null. Tried calling: []("forecastday")

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

This is the code `

```dart
class WeatherModel {
  String date;
  double temp;
  double maxTemp;
  double minTemp;
  String weatherStateName;

  WeatherModel(
      {required this.date,
      required this.temp,
      required this.maxTemp,
      required this.minTemp,
      required this.weatherStateName});

  factory WeatherModel.fromJson(dynamic data) {
    var jsonData = data['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['day'];
    

    return WeatherModel(
        date: data['location']['localtime'];
        temp: jsonData['avgtemp_c'];
        maxTemp: jsonData['maxtemp_c'];
        minTemp: jsonData['mintemp_c'];
        weatherStateName: jsonData['condition']['text']);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'tem = $temp minTemp = $minTemp date = $date';
  }
}
```

this image

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

this is an error message.

The method '[]' was called on null.
Tried calling: .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting null data from `var jsonData = data['forecast']['forecastday'][0]['day'];` You can accept null data like including `?` `data['forecast']?['forecastday']?[0]?['day'];` , not sure `?[0]?` is needed

```dart
class WeatherModel {
  String? date;
  double? temp;
  double? maxTemp;
  double? minTemp;
  String? weatherStateName;

  WeatherModel(
      {required this.date,
      required this.temp,
      required this.maxTemp,
      required this.minTemp,
      required this.weatherStateName});

  factory WeatherModel.fromJson(dynamic data) {
    var jsonData = data['forecast']?['forecastday']?[0]?['day'];

    return WeatherModel(
        date: data?['location']['localtime'] ?? "",
        temp: double.tryParse("${jsonData['avgtemp_c']}"),
        maxTemp: double.tryParse("${jsonData['maxtemp_c']}"),
        minTemp: double.tryParse("${jsonData['mintemp_c']}"),
        weatherStateName: jsonData?['condition']?['text']);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'tem = $temp minTemp = $minTemp date = $date';
  }
}
```

You can make filed nullable for safety

Comment: another error got appeared. this is error message : Tried calling: []("avgtemp_c"))

Comment: Hope it is null issue ?

Comment: yeah it is null []("avgtemp_c"))

Comment: It is risky to provide num like this. try `temp: double.tryParse(jsonData?['avgtemp_c'])??0.0,`

Comment: it worked but it give another error. the message is 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: `weatherStateName` i believe ? try `weatherStateName: jsonData?['condition']?['text'] ?? "got null"`

Comment: it give the error in this line.  temp: double.tryParse(jsonData?['avgtemp_c']) ?? 0.0,

Comment: ok try now, it would be easier if could include response data.

Comment: really am sorry for bothering you but  I didn't get you what you mean

Comment: try current snippet , if fails print `jsonData` and include on question.

Comment: alright I get it

Comment: nothing happened still in the same error dud

Comment: what is the current error and about json response

Comment: ok try current nullable model. also while using variable you need to do a null check or just provide default value like `??""`

Comment: alright I'll try it

Comment: @basbos If you think an answer is helpful, do not forget to upvote and accept it.

Comment: I fix it my problem M.rs Yeasin Sheikh. really appreciate your help thanx a lot dud

Comment: Np, when you like to use api, try accepting null and also match dataType with api response, you can use postman for checking api